# Как считать большой Numpy файл?

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется файл типа .npy размером ~ 4гб
при его считывании при помощи:`np.load()`

выдает ошибку: `errno 5 input output error`

Как можно считать этот файл?

P.S. в нем лежит матрица размерностью (87000,64,64,3)

Comment: numpy.memmap() вам не поможет?

Comment: Не помогло, совершенно в ином виде считывается

Comment: а обязательно ли нужно читать его целиком в память?